# Cyberoam : Issue Web Filter Policy

Tags: security

I am a beginner,

I want to Block a Specific Website in cyberoam
I have followed this tutorial : [Block a Specific Website](http://kb.cyberoam.com/default.asp?id=2395)
to block a Specific Website in cyberoam.
the first URL has been blocked successfully, but when I tried to block another website with the same method did not work.
I don't know where is my mistake
Thanks by advance

Comment: Can you post your policy?  Otherwise we don't know where your mistake is either.

Comment: I agree with @RonTrunk. Of the top of my hat I would say that you implemented a rule, then an explicit allow with another rule following this last one. In this case, it will never get to the 3rd rule implemented and will always be matched (if not matched by the first) by the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the sites using https? You should take a look at blocking https enabled and follow that guide.

Also some google sites now use their new QUIC protocol and even enabling https will not block it so you need to block that as well and then block the sites using the normal https blocking method.